# LWJGL OpenGL texturing not correct

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, texturing

I'm trying to make a simple button in OpenGL/LWJGL,

I can render my 2D QUAD correctly, but when i implement the texture, only about 3/4 parts of the whole quad gets textured, like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60223805/glerror1.png

and if i remove the texture coords i get this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60223805/glerror2.png

```
     none.bind();

     co.Enable2D_GUI();
     GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(co.width/2-200, co.height/2);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(co.width/2+none.getTextureWidth(),co.height/2);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(co.width/2+none.getTextureWidth(), co.height/2+none.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(co.width/2-200, co.height/2+none.getTextureHeight());
     GL11.glEnd();
     co.Disable2D_GUI();
```

where none is an Texture (from slick-util library) and the functions Enable2D_GUI and Disable2D_GUI just enables and disable ortho and stuff.

What can be wrong? I'm very new to OpenGL so im sorry if my question is a bit nooby

This is my Enable2D_GUI and Disable2D_GUI functions:

```
    public void Enable2D_GUI() {

     GL11.glMatrixMode (GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
     GL11.glPushMatrix();
     GL11.glLoadIdentity ();
     GL11.glOrtho (0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
     GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     GL11.glMatrixMode (GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
     GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}

public void Disable2D_GUI() {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();

    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Now when I test it with a 3D QUAD it doesnt work either, same result. This is my OpenGL init code:

```
           GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
       GL11.glClearColor(0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
       GL11.glClearDepth(1.0); 
       GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
       GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL); 

       GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

       GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); 
       GL11.glLoadIdentity();

       GLU.gluPerspective(
             45.0f,
             (float)width/(float)height,
             0.5f,
             50.0f);


       GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
       GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
```

Comment: Could you add the actual texture image file also?

Comment: Could you comment the link to the image then?

Comment: @Vallentin sure: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60223805/button_none.png

Comment: Okay so you must be doing something else wrong, because I just used the exact same code as you and this is my result. http://gyazo.com/65dae85d4a4d9ed2064f1d2c590a605e.png

Comment: Hmm. Okay I'll check it out more in-depth and i'll try to find a soulution

Comment: Well okay then, but you can also post some more code!

Comment: Sure haha I'll update it

Comment: Do you find a solution? @Vallentin

Comment: Yea I just found something that worked for me! Posting answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` and also not adding or performing state switches in the correct order.

In you init code you need to change it to the following.

```
GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); 
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.5f, 50.0f);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); 
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glClearColor(0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glClearDepth(1.0);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
```

You don't have to perform state switches after the `glLoadMatrix` and `glLoadIdentity` though it would be better doing so. 1 The code is more readable. 2 Some things gets reset after calling `glLoadIdentity` though just the stuff about and within the Matrix itself.

Then you also need to fix your `Enable2D_GUI` and `Disable2D_GUI` to the following.

**Enable2D_GUI**

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0f, 1f, -1f);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

**Disable2D_GUI**

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Aleast of what I know you can not use the `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` in between `glMatrixMode` and `glLoadIdentity` calls. *I could be mistaking* Then I also added the `glLoadIdentity` calls instead to reset the Matrices.

Comment: I'm not at home right now but I'll try it when i get home! Thanks in advance!